# Either Right Left how to read value

Tags: haskell

I am trying to read CSV file which I succeded with some examples. Here is what I've got

```
*Main System.IO> let result=parseCSV contents
*Main System.IO> result
Right [["Name","Value","Amount"],["Rob","1","10"],["Bob","1.42","15.3"],["Tom","452.2","23.1"]]
```

But If I try to read value from this array I get an error

```
*Main System.IO> head result

<interactive>:21:6:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a0]'
            with actual type `Either ParseError [[String]]'
In the first argument of `head', namely `result'
In the expression: head result
In an equation for `it': it = head result
```

So how can I get Rid of the Right and actually use the list ?

```
*Main System.IO> :t result
result :: Either ParseError [[String]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the `Right`, you need to decide what to do when you get an error instead. If you just want to get an empty result you could use:

```
justTheResult :: [[[Char]]]
justTheResult = either (const []) id result
```

If you want an error to be raised, you could use:

```
justTheResult :: [[[Char]]]
justTheResult = either (const $ error "Couldn't parse CSV") id result
```

If you want to keep the error for later, but do something with the result, you could instead use `Either`'s `Functor (Either e)` instance:

```
errorOrNumberOfRows :: Either ParseError Int
errorOrNumberOfRows = fmap length result
```

Now you'll be in the same place accessing that `Int` length

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
*Main System.IO> let (Right result) = parseCSV contents
*Main System.IO> head result
```

Comment: Thanks that worked well. Just small typo
let (Right result) = parseCSV contents

Comment: This will give a runtime pattern-matching error if the result *isn't* `Right`, however. Be warned.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to ignore the error, the following shoud do the job:

```
either (const []) id (parseCSV contents)
```

It will give you an empty list in case of parse errors.